# how to search like LIKe operator in sql in hash map in java

Tags: java

I want to search a hash map depending on the user input. Suppose a user give value 'A',I have to display starting with A company name and if user give value 'AB' I have to display starting with AB company name. I am storing company name in hash map

Answer (score 11):

1. Use a [NavigableSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html).

   **Example:**

   ```
   NavigableSet<String> company=new TreeSet<String>(); 
   Set<String> filteredSet=company.tailSet(prefix);
   for(String str:filteredSet) {
    if(str.startsWith(prefix))
     //add to list
    else
     break;
   }
   ```
2. Use a [radix tree](http://code.google.com/p/radixtree/) [[wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) or [trie](http://code.google.com/p/trie/) [[wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) if you are concerned about performance.The radix tree is more memory efficient compared to a trie.

Comment: @user426344 : Also check this [blog on auto-completion](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/02/three-autocomplete-implementations.html)

Answer (score 3):

Hash maps are only really good at finding exact matches based on some idea of equality which can be appropriately hashed.

Two options:

- Just go with a list instead, and search it linearly. For relatively small amounts of data, this is likely to work absolutely fine.
- Find or implement a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (or prefix tree) which will basically start at a root node and descend for each character the user has typed - the results are all "valid endpoint" nodes below the node reached at the end of descending the user input.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the keyset and check each key. For example:

```
final String searchPrefix = "AB";
for(String key : map.keySet()){
    if(key.startsWith(searchPrefix)){
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Or, you can loop over the entries in the map.

```
final String searchPrefix = "AB";
for(Entry<String,String> e : map.entrySet()){
    if(e.getKey().startsWith(searchPrefix)){
        System.out.println(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look into regex (regular expressions)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

your company names are Strings then you can use

```
String regex = "A*";
myString.matches(regex);
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me. For a simple prefix search, regex is overkill... what's wrong with `String.startsWith`?

Comment: Nothing, but the question was how to do LIKE, I suggest regex because he might want to do more complex test later. if its just to do :startwith test then yes and no its an overkill. ("yes" because there is a shorter way to write it, "no" because I think Java uses also regex to do this in the background).

Comment: @user440336 No, java iterates over the underlying char arrays, which is a lot more efficient than regex. especially since if you use `String.matches()` multiple times, the same pattern is compiled over and over again (`str.matches(pattern)` is a shortcut for `Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str).matches()`)

Comment: ok then I agree if your only looking for the beginning then String.startsWith i smore effecient. I never really use regex in Java and just assumed it would be as effecient as other languages.