# How to search like LIKE operator in sql in arraylist in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to search like LIKe operator in sql in hash map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203038/how-to-search-like-like-operator-in-sql-in-hash-map-in-java)

Hi friends,

I am adding hashmap in arraylist. The hashmap values contain the company name. My requirment is that if the user types 'A' value, I have to display all the values starting with 'A' company name. If the user types 'AB' value, I have to display all the values starting with 'AB'Company name. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

My code for adding the values:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> companylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

StockParser stockParser=new StockParser();
       stockparsedvalue=stockParser.parseXmlArticle(stockservicevalue);
       for(int i=0;i<stockparsedvalue.size();i++)
       {
          StockParserSet parserSet=(StockParserSet)stockparsedvalue.get(i); 
          mapValue=new HashMap<String, String>();                    

          mapValue.put("companyname"+i, parserSet.getCompanyname());
          companylist.add(mapValue);

       }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over list and look at each entry in the map to see if the value starts with what you are looking for. For example:

```
    final String prefix = "AB";
    for(HashMap<String,String> map : companylist){
        for(Entry<String,String> e: map.entrySet()){
            String companyName = e.getValue();
            if(companyName.startsWith(prefix)){
                System.out.println(companyName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the simplest way if you can afford to iterate over the whole list. You might want to retain a new list of the entries that match if you want to refine the list as the user keeps typing, for an easy speed-up.