# How to check equalignorecase with startsWith in hashmap in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to search like LIKe operator in sql in hash map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203038/how-to-search-like-like-operator-in-sql-in-hash-map-in-java)

Hi

How to check equalignorecase with startsWith in hashmap in java
give example

Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. The more effort you put into your question, the better the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive. Can you expand (dramatically) on what **exactly** it is you need help with?

Comment: Please stop asking basically the same question again and again. Read the answer you've already got in your other questions.

Comment: @Jon, who knows, probably in one of those question he may actually phrase it properly  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding your question.  However, from what I can deduce:

Keys in a `HashMap` are compared for equality using the equals(Object o) operation.  You cannot change this.  However, you can implement your own key, for example to perform a case-insensitive comparison:

```
public class Key {
  private final String s;
  private final int hashCode;

  public Key(String s) {
    this.s = s;
    this.hashCode = s.toUpperCase().hashCode();
  }

  public int hashCode() { return hashCode; }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    } else if (o instanceof Key) {
      return this.s.equalsIgnoreCase(((Key)o).s);
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

Given:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

You may call:

```
map.get( someKey ).equalsIgnoreCase( someValue )
```

and

```
 map.get( someKey ).startsWith( someOtherValue );
```

Comment: Yeah maybe that's what he meant ... I have no idea :-)

Comment: @Adamski who knows!! :-/

Comment: I am storing company name in hash map .if the user type "A" it will equalignorecase check with map value and display to all the company start with A